# Why I can't change value in nested Models?

Tags: ios, swift, model, nested

I have 2 class , First class has a property which inheritance from second class

```
class FirstModel{
var firstType : Secondmodel?
}
class Secondmodel{
   var secondType : Int?

}
```

Now I want to set a value to  `secondType` so I code

```
    var Modelll = FirstModel()
    Modelll.firstType?.secondType = 100
```

When I try to read this property with `print(Modelll.firstType?.secondType)` it return `nil`
So first question is why I couldn't read this

But I try to do this

```
    var Modelll = FirstModel()
    var ModelSecond = Secondmodel()
    ModelSecond.secondType = 100
    Modelll.firstType = ModelSecond
    print(Modelll.firstType?.secondType)
```

It works perfectly , printed out `Optional(100)` I really dont understand whats going on behind the scene. Can anyone explain this?

Comment: In first case you did not initalise firstType, and you directly assigned it a value which is nil and nil

Answer (score 1):

First of all, all variables and constant should be named with lowercased symbol. With Uppercased only names of classes, structs, protocols, enums etc

You problem is that when You init FirstModel, firstType variable is nil by default

```
var model = FirstModel()
print(model.firstType) //prints nil
```

so You need to do

```
var model = FirstModel()
model.firstType = SecondModel() //use camel case in naming
model.firstType?.secondType = 100
print(model.firstType?.secondType) // prints 100
```

Answer (score 0):

Ammm.. Because you don't initiate firstType with an instance in your first try.
You can add something like this

```
class FirstModel{
  var firstType : Secondmodel?
  
  init() {
    self.firstType = Secondmodel()
  }
}
```

But this is not exactly how things should be done. Here is not a problem of nesting, you just don't give a value in firstyType property.

The best case should be like:

```
class Secondmodel{
  var secondType : Int?

  init(secondType: Int) {
    self.secondType = secondType
  }
}

var modelll = FirstModel()
modelll.firstType = SecondModel(secondType: 100)
```

You should read more about OOP.
..and objects should not be named with capital letters